# Centering form in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I am having issues centering a form in Bootstrap. The form includes name and comment box including a post button.

This is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<form id ="Form" onsubmit ="return false">
<div class="mx-auto"style="width: 200px;"> 
  <label for="usr">Name:</label>
  <input type="text"  id="name" >
<br>
<br>
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onClick ="myFunction()">Post</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <ul id="adduserinput"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When you run the code, the form only appears on the left side of the page. It won't center the page. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

This would help you in making your form center of page.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh; // optional this is only to get full height
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #Form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="Form" onsubmit="return false">
      <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
        <label for="usr">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button onClick="myFunction()">Post</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <ul id="adduserinput"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The mx-auto class does not work for Bootstrap 3. If you use Bootstrap 4, then it will work no problem. If you need to use Bootstrap 3, then put your own style with a margin: 0 auto;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
    <form id="Form" onsubmit="return false">
      <label for="usr">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
      <br>
      <button onClick="myFunction()">Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <ul id="adduserinput">
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @MichaelvE said, the `mx-auto` works for Bootstrap 4, not 3.
A method I use with 3 is adding the class `text-center` to the form tag (or wrapping them all inside a `<div class="text-center">...</div>`. Works fine for me.

Note: It does not center only text, as the name implies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the Bootstrap way, then you can go with **col** and **col offset** classes. Also, try to avoid fixed width elements if you want it to be responsive on all screen sizes. Even more, use **form-groups** classes for wrap labels and they related input. I show you an example of this (you can play with the browser's width):

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="Form" onsubmit="return false">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" style="resize:vertical"></textarea>
      </div>          
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunction()">
        Post
      </button>  
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

As you can note, the formulary is centered on **small, medium and large** screen sizes, but it use the full width on **extra small** devices. Hope this helps you.